# How to query on trackhistory property of an object?

Tags: field-history

I am attempting to produce a report which would show all of the objects which have Field Tracking History enabled, as well as the fields which are been tracked.

I see here that it is a property : 
[Metadata types](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring14/release-notes/rn_api_meta.htm)

But I can't figure out how to use that to produce a list. I've been trying to hack it in Workbench, but I can't really get it right.

I also tried using this app : [Config Workbook](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N30000000q4evEAA)

But that will only export the analysis into separate spreadsheets for each object, which is about 200 in my case. It would be a total nightmare to fish through the results like that.

Does anybody have any ideas on this ? I

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution is to execute an SOQL to query on `FieldDefinition` by filtering on `IsFieldHistoryTracked` to list all fields for which history tracking is enabled and their corresponding objects:

```
SELECT DeveloperName,EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName 
from FieldDefinition 
where EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName != null 
and IsFieldHistoryTracked = true
```

`EntityDefinition.QualifiedApiName` represents the custom or standard object API name

`DeveloperName` from `FieldDefinition` represents the custom or standard field API name for that object

**References**:

[FieldDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_fielddefinition.htm) and 
[EntityDefinition](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_entitydefinition.htm)

Comment: @zoom_v does the above proposed solution help in resolving your question ?